# Time difference

Tags: php

I am making quiz module. I have to find that how much time user take to finish that quiz. For that I am doing some code that is I given below:

```
$_SESSION['start'] = mktime(date('h'), date('i'), date('s'), date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
$_SESSION['endtime'] = mktime(date('h'), date('i'), date('s'), date("m")  , date("d"), date("Y"));
if(isset($_SESSION['endtime']))
{
    $date1 = $_SESSION['start']; 
    $date2 = $_SESSION['endtime'];
    $dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    $fullHours = sprintf("%02d",floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24))/(60*60)));
    $fullMinutes = sprintf("%02d",floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24)-($fullHours*60*60))/60));
    $fullSec = sprintf("%02d",floor(($dateDiff-($fullDays*60*60*24)-($fullHours*60*60)-($fullMinutes*60))));
    $time="$fullHours:$fullMinutes:$fullSec";   
}
else
{
    $time="over";
}
```

But do not get proper time. What I can do?

Comment: Do you realy create session vars `start` and `endtime` every time when you refresh page?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['starttime']))
{
    $date1 = $_SESSION['starttime']; 
    $date2 = time();
    $dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
    $time=date('H:i:s', $dateDiff); // thank you Wilmer :)   
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
    $time="00:00:00";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, haven't tested it though:

```
$_SESSION['start'] = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));
$_SESSION['endtime'] = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));
if(isset($_SESSION['endtime']))
{
    $date1 = $_SESSION['start']; 
    $date2 = $_SESSION['endtime'];
    $dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
    $time=date('H:i:s', $dateDiff);   
}
else
{
    $time="over";
}
```